# Обособление конструкции "родом из США"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Это верно, что я обособил запятыми конструкцию "родом из США" в таком предложении:

"**Джефф Монсон, родом из США, представлял на этом бое Россию**"?

Comment: Если Джефф Монсон учавствовал в бое, то "в этом бое", а если только просутствовал, то "на этом бое".

Answer (score 5):

В примере, который Вы привели, обособление факультативно.

Приложения, присоединяемые к определяемому слову с помощью слов по имени, по фамилии, по прозвищу, ***родом,*** обособляются факультативно в том случае, если оборотам с этими словами придаётся в речи характер добавочного сообщения-уточнения, что ведёт к их логическому и интонационному выделению.

> Ср.: 1)  Мой друг, родом с Урала, решил в каникулы поехать к себе на родину.
>   Мой друг родом с Урала решил в каникулы поехать к себе на родину.

Answer (score 2):

Да.

Губернатор, родом из польских жидов, чувствовал какое-то органическое отвращение к дуэлям и вообще в этом случае хлопотал, чтобы все-таки во вверенном ему крае не произошло комеражу. [А. Ф. Писемский. Русские лгуны (1865)]